# Javascript Decorators, detect context

Tags: javascript, decorator, ecmascript-next

I am writing some decorator(factory) functions which can be used as decorators but also called directly. It would certainly be best to call them the same way either if they are mounted to some class/method/property/... or called directly. Is it possible to detect if the function was called as a decorator or a "normal" function without passing in additional properties or calling the actual decorator function inside the factory?

**Decorator**

```
export function DecoratorFactory(opts) {
    // detect if it was called as a function
    if(isFunctionCall) return 'Was called as function';

    return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
        // do something
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

**Usage**

as Function

```
DecoratorFactory({...}) === 'Was called as function';
```

as Decorator

```
class Test {

  @DecoratorFactory({...})
  testDecorator() {
    //modified function
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: It's not possible. Because decorators are just functions that can be called manually, too. You can code it to be called with `new` when being called manually.

Comment: Regarding ES7 vs next, sorry about that, I searched a little bit beforehand and found some SO questions and blog posts that referred to it as ES7. @estus thanks, I guess I need to figure out what's best (new or adding an additional argument)

Comment: @KenavR Btw, Angular 2 uses it with `new` when decorators are called manually (it's more complex there, but differentiating manual calls like `this instanceof Decorator` likely was one of the reasons to do that).

Comment: @Bergi Yes, had a good discussion on ES.next with Felix Kling before. That's why I call this a 'de facto' synonym. And as a de jure synonym of ES2016, it's unlikely that ES7 had ever been used on SO (ES2016 is low profile per se, and the guys who use it already know that ES7 isn't a legit name for the spec). Ok, let's keep on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to differentiate the call of decorator function, because in the end it's just a function that is being called.

Similarly, it's not possible to differentiate if a decorator was specified without (`@DecoratorFactory testDecorator() ...`)  or with arguments (`@DecoratorFactory(...) testDecorator() ...`) if they cannot be reliably duck-typed.

A way to tell if a decorator was called directly is to conventionally call it with `new`. It makes sense since it is already follows PascalCase naming convention and suggests that it is constructor function:

```
export function DecoratorFactory(opts) {
    if(this instanceof DecoratorFactory)
    // or for native ES6,
    // if(new.target)
        return 'Was called as function';

    return (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
        // do something
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

This is the recipe that was used in Angular for annotations (decorators), for instance; they are required to be called with `new` when being applied manually.